# Parse array-like string containing variable names to array

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, math, matrix

I have a default setup where I'm defining a bunch of variables like

```
let a="a", b="b", c="c", d="d", ...
```

and I got a **multidimensional array** `(as string)` that is using these variables as values like ...

```
let matrixString = // (typeof matrixString === "string")
 `[
    [a, b, c, d, a],
    [b, b, c, d, a],
    [c, c, a, a, d]
  ]`
```

... and I'd like to **parse** this string using `"JSON.parse()"` to get a **real array** from **the string** but it looks like there is a issue parsing a string with variables inside because I get the error-message

```
JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "a"
```

Please have a look at my example:

```js
/* ** default setup ** */
let a="a", b="b", c="c", d="d";
let matrix =  [
  [a, b, c, d, a],
  [b, b, c, d, a],
  [c, c, a, a, d]
]

console.log(matrix)



/* ** here is the issue ** */
let matrixAsString = `[
                        [a, b, c, d, a],
                        [b, b, c, d, a],
                        [c, c, a, a, d]
                      ]`;
try {
  let parsedMatrix = JSON.parse(matrixAsString)
  console.log(parsedMatrix)
} catch(error) {
  // error = 'JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "a"'
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`) 
}
```

How to fix this without using a workaround like mapping the string and adding `""` between or using `"eval()"`. **Is there a method?**

Comment: Don't use `JSON.parse()` if you don't have JSON to parse.

Comment: Do you have any other approach instead of using JSON.parse?

Comment: Write your own parsing method. Or consider using http://www.relaxedjson.org/

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://js-chfrhm.stackblitz.io

Comment: Why not just write the string in the form of some key, value pair of an object and then use JSON.parse on it? For example you could wrap the string that you have now in ``{data: ${2dArrayString}}``.

Comment: There is no way to evaluate that string as it is without using `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `JSON.parse()` if you don't have `JSON` to parse in the first place. If you need a more loose definition of JSON to work for you, consider something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/really-relaxed-json.

In this case, though, what you are looking for might be **template literals**:

```js
/* ** default setup ** */
let a="1", b="2", c="3", d="4";
let matrix =  [
  [a, b, c, d, a],
  [b, b, c, d, a],
  [c, c, a, a, d]
]

console.log(matrix)

let matrixAsTemplateLiteral = `[
                        [${a}, ${b}, ${c}, ${d}, ${a}],
                        [${b}, ${b}, ${c}, ${d}, ${a}],
                        [${c}, ${c}, ${a}, ${a}, ${d}]
                      ]`;
console.log(matrixAsTemplateLiteral);
```